# Excel VBA Autofill

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA in Access that exports data to Excel into separate sheets. The data comes in unformatted so I am going to create a macro that will format it. The export is inventory data (price of an item and quantity on hand) for multiple locations. The autofill will be a calculation of price*quantity autofilled to the end of the data. The locations do no have the same amount of data in their sheets; I originally tried grouping all the sheets together and just autofilling the first sheet. This did not work. Can anyone direct me to the proper way to do this using a macro or VBA?

Note: The amount of data may change when a new inventory count comes in so the code cannot reference a specific cell in each sheet as the last row.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Which columns are you using for *price* and for *quantity* ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent it's columns D and E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses column **F** for the products.  Select each sheet and run this macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        Cells(i, "F") = Cells(i, "D") * Cells(i, "E")
    Next i
End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Now that `dural()` is working, we can call it from:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Call dural
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch error in the code. This may be due to the fact that the data in columns D and E have decimal values?

Comment: @KScott  The data in columns **D** and **E** must be numeric.....If there are column headers, start the `For` loop with ***2*** rather than ***1***

Comment: Great. That works great. What is the best way to get this to run on each sheet? Note the first two sheets contain a summary of the other so that should not be included in the loop.

Comment: See my **EDIT#1:**